# Input Field Lookup not working after Spring 18

Tags: salesforce1-app, inputfield

After the Spring 18 release suddenly The Input field (Type lookup) stop working. When I click on lookup icon nothing happens. This issue coming in iPhone/iPad Salesforce App.

I try to reproduce this issue in personal org but in my org when I try to click the Icon I get the error URL doesn't not exist. Can anyone else also confirm this behaviour or this is a known issue.

Here is a sample code which you can try

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false">
    <style>
        .lookupInput
        {
            display: inline;
            vertical-align: middle;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        .lookupInput img
        {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            margin-right: .25em;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .lookupInput .disabled
        {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }
        .lookupInput .emptyDependentLookup
        {
            font-style: italic;
        }
        .lookupInput input[readonly]
        {
            background-color: #e6e6e6;
            border: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
            color: #333;
            cursor: default;
        }
        .lookupInput a.readOnly
        {
            float: right;
        }
        .lookupInput span.readOnly
        {
            display: block;
            white-space: normal;
        }
        .lookupInput span.totalSummary
        {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .inlineEditRequiredDiv .lookupInput img,.inlineEditDiv .lookupInput img
        {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .quickCreateModule .lookupInput input {
            max-width: 155px
        }
        .lookupIcon {
            background-image: url(/img/func_icons/util/lookup20.gif);
            background-position: 0 0;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-position: top left
        }
        .lookupIconOn {
            background-image: url(/img/func_icons/util/lookup20.gif);
            background-position: 0 0;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-position: top right
        }

    </style>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.AccountID}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```